# Increasing the movement speed of an AI sprite

Tags: python, pygame

My enemy sprite in my game move relatively slow. When i increase the speed to any speed over 1 they move really fast in the left direction and kind of slow in the right direction. Does anyone know the reason behind this?

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self,x,y,width = 60, height = 55):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.speed = 1

    self.s0 = pygame.image.load("Images/Enemy/s0.png")
    s1 = pygame.image.load("Images/Enemy/s1.png")
    s2 = pygame.image.load("Images/Enemy/s2.png")
    s3 = pygame.image.load("Images/Enemy/s3.png")
    rs0 = pygame.transform.flip(self.s0 ,True, False)
    rs1 = pygame.transform.flip(s1 ,True, False)
    rs2 = pygame.transform.flip(s2 ,True, False)
    rs3 = pygame.transform.flip(s3 ,True, False)

    self.attack = pygame.image.load("Images/Enemy/attack.png")
    self.rattack = pygame.image.load("Images/Enemy/rotatedattack.png")

    self.images = []
    self.images.append(self.s0)
    self.images.append(s1)
    self.images.append(s2)
    self.images.append(s3)

    self.rotated_images = []
    self.rotated_images.append(rs0)
    self.rotated_images.append(rs1)
    self.rotated_images.append(rs2)
    self.rotated_images.append(rs3)     

    self.deadimages= [self.attack]
    self.index = 0
    self.TimeNum=0
    self.TimeTarget=10

    self.image = self.images[self.index]
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,width,height)

    self.playercollision = False
    self.Timer = 0

def update(self,player):

    if self.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
        print("hey")
        self.Timer += 1
        if self.Timer >= 10:
            if self.rect.x > player.rect.x:
                self.image = self.attack

            if self.rect.x < player.rect.x:
                self.image = self.rattack

    if player.rect.x == 0:
        self.image = self.s0

def Enemy1Move(self,player):
    if player.rect.x > 0 and player.rect.x < 655:

        if self.rect.x < player.rect.x:
            self.rect.x += self.speed
            self.TimeNum+=1
            if self.TimeNum == self.TimeTarget:
                self.index +=1
                if self.index >= len(self.rotated_images):
                    self.index = 0
                self.image = self.rotated_images[self.index]

                self.TimeNum = 0

        if self.rect.x > player.rect.x:
            self.rect.x -= self.speed
            self.TimeNum +=1
            if self.TimeNum == self.TimeTarget:
                self.index +=1
                if self.index >= len(self.images):
                    self.index = 0
                self.image = self.images[self.index]

                self.TimeNum = 0
```

Comment: Both conditions in the code to update the enemy position can get used in the same call.

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you mean?

Comment: code looks good - maybe `print()`  enemy position in many places in code to see how it changed. Maybe first you add speed to position but later you substract some value from position and enemy moves slower.

Comment: btw: always add tag `python` - it makes code is colored and more readable.

Comment: ok i will do but yh there is no other code slowing down my enemy in one direction

Comment: did you check all code - not only Enemy class? Sometimes code is doing something different than we expect. `print` helps to see it.

Comment: I printed the enemy x value and it was moving much faster in one direction than the other. What else should i print to check?

Answer (score 1):

As Jongware already sad in a comment, the issue is probably that both `if`  statements can be true in the same call to `Enemy1Move`.

Say `self.speed` is 5, `self.rect.x` is 100, and `player.rect.x` is 102.

Now `if self.rect.x < player.rect.x:` is true, and `self.rect.x += self.speed` changes `self.rect.x` to 105.

While the function is still running, the next `if` statement `if self.rect.x > player.rect.x:` is also true, and `self.rect.x -= self.speed` changes `self.rect.x` back to 100.

Consider using `elif`:

```
if self.rect.x < player.rect.x:
    self.rect.x += self.speed
    ...
elif self.rect.x > player.rect.x:
    self.rect.x -= self.speed
    ...
```